# Optimizing Google Cloud DNS for users from specific location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

my website receives most of the traffic from a specific country. Though I am using Google cloud DNS, I am observing DNS lookup time to hover in the range of 200 to 300 ms which is quite slow I guess. Is there any extra optimization on Cloud DNS that will help to resolve DNS queries faster in my country of interest?

Answer (score 1):

> I am observing DNS lookup time to hover in the range of 200 to 300 ms
>   which is quite slow I guess.

This neither slow nor fast. However, the performance of your Internet connection and provider can have a big impact on this number. First remove your Internet connection from the equation to determine so that you can determine how much of the delay is caused by Google -> your provider and then your provider -> your computer.

> Is there any extra optimization on Cloud DNS that will help to resolve
>   DNS queries faster in my country of interest?

You are leaving our details. What country? How are you testing queries?

Use an Internet DNS testing service that will report response time from points around the world.  This will provide you with more realistic data. Testing from a single Internet connection is pointless unless that is the source of all your traffic.

However, there are no settings you can change in Google Cloud DNS that will affect geolocation response times.

The response time for DNS has very little to do with Internet performance of a website unless you set the TTL for DNS resource records to be very short. A client and the DNS servers around the world will look up your DNS resource records once, cache the result and use the resulting IP address for traffic until the TTL expires. This means that for most traffic, your DNS server is not involved. I am oversimplifying the process of resource record lookup and caching around the world.

In summary, you are focussing on something that really does not matter and that you cannot change.